# How to save data from form field in Model with One to One reltionship with a Model inheriting from AbstractUser

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a field called org model called ScrummyUser with a one to one field with a model called User which inherits from AbstractUser model, how do I save data from the form field into the scrummyuser model

This is the Organization Model

```py
class Organization(models.Model):
    organization = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.organization
```

This is the ScrummyUser model

```py
class ScrummyUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='scrummy_profile')

    role= models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=role, blank=True, null=True, default='DEV')
    org = models.ForeignKey(Organization, max_length=255, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
```

This is the ScrummySignup form

```py
class ScrummySignUpForm(UserCreationForm):

    role = forms.ChoiceField(choices=role, required=False)
    org = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Organization.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.Select
    )

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name','username' ,'email']

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_user = True
        user.save()
        scrummy = ScrummyUser.objects.create(user=user, role=role)

        return user
```

It throws me this errormessage

```py
 scrummy = ScrummyUser.objects.create(user=user, role=role, org=org)
NameError: name 'org' is not defined
```

which is obvious but I am looking for another approach to save the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I figured this out, after defining a variable org as a modelchoicefield, i passed it unto the fields for user model as a user form field before saving it into the scrummyuser model.

Answer (score 0):

for access `CutomUser` with Abstract you should get User of `settings`:

```
from django.conf import settings
class ScrummyUser(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
       primary_key=True, related_name='scrummy_profile')
```

[AbstractUser link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/)

Comment: Authentication is not my problem, my problem is only the org form field that is refusing to save, which is being handled incorrectly in the form